# How to correctly pass an array to struct

Tags: c, string, for-loop, struct

**Question Edited**

I'm very new in C, and here.

Is it possible for an array return its value via a struct?

Although I'm trying to process each character in List[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4}, however, it only sticks at 1 and only prints 575757 rather than

My struct

```
struct Count numbers() {                                    
struct Count numbers;
int List[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {         //It might be something in my for loop
    numbers.intOne= List[i] + 4;   // 1 + 4
    numbers.intTwo= List[i] + 6;   // 1 + 6     
    return numbers;
}
};
```

This only prints 575757, i wish this to print 576879

```
void printCode(struct Count numbers) {
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("%i%i", numbers.intOne, numbers.intTwo); 

}
}
```

The main

```
int main() {
int i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    numbers();
    printCode(numbers());
    getchar();
}

}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by "string", perhaps you're forgetting that a string is an array of *characters* instead of an array of integers.

Comment: Also you return on the *first* iteration of `for` loop which makes the loop totally meaningless

Comment: *"It only stucks at '4352'."* => move the return statement *out of the loop*.

Comment: What string? What do you mean "couldn't pass the value [20]"? This is very unclear, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Lundin
i'm trying to make the string goes to another code, which is the '3615' in Code[20]

Comment: That's not a string. You'll need to read a C programming book to straighten out the terms.

Comment: @Thank you, noted that. Am i messing with an array so far?

Answer (score 1):

> it only stucks at '4352'

You are returning from `decode` soon after processing the first element of the `output` array which is `4352`. So the other elements of `check` and `param` arrays do not get filled up.

In any case, `check` and `param` are arrays local to the `decode` function and the values of their elements cannot be used outside the function.

Comment: That's incorrect, rest of the elements are initialized as if by assigned 0.

Comment: Sorry, `split` is uninitialized.

Comment: Yes, the answer is incorrect. But is `split` not being initialized in the `for` loop?

Comment: ah it is, I saw only that there were some xors and stuff. It makes even less sense now.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Updated the answer. But don't know if it is really useful. Will wait for a while for confirmation from OP and delete the answer if not useful.

Comment: Pretty sure it is because the `return` happens on the first iteration.

Comment: @P.W Thank you for your answer, I honestly use `check` and  `param` only to print the conditions. All i need was to pass the `split` to struct.

Comment: @P.W But however i still don't know the implementation of it. Did i declare my function too early? https://pastebin.com/ycWT3KGk (is pastebin ok?) This is my early code and it was working before i put struct.

Comment: @origamimagician: are you getting the expected output after each print statement?

Comment: @P.W Yes. But i have to use a struct. I did't know what is going on too

Comment: @origamimagician: Is it a requirement for an assignment that you must use a struct?

Comment: @P.W yes it is, a challenge.

Comment: @origamimagician: Why not use a `char` array within a struct and perform operations on the elements of the array and `return` the struct?

Comment: @P.W i understand what is that. So i'll declare my array and also perform operations which both are inside the struct, and returns both values (char1, and char2)? Thank you so much in prior!